# Why a traceroute to a dynamic ip is different from static ip addresses?

Tags: networking, ping, traceroute

Sorry I can't show you an output of a traceroute atm. Anyways, i find it strange when i try pinging a dynamic ip from the same ISP and get a good route and ping times. Where if i pinged their static ip address, it would takes longer or maybe a bad route to it. Is that normal? Are these dynamic and static ip addresses configured seperately from the ISP?

Comment: "Static" or "dynamic" is not a property of the IP address. (Or in a sense, all IP addresses are static: 1.2.3.4 is always 1.2.3.4. Incidentally, the system it is assigned to can change over time.)

Comment: I don't care whether it's dynamic or static. my route changes completely when i use either one of them. Either way, both work differently on deciding where to pick the required routes. So how can you explain that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An ISP that do network attribution change nothing, as each modem cable and such gear report to the ISP server upstream.

Having a static IP just mean your router is not configured to ask an IP from a DHCP server from the ISP, but the packet, or the route use the same physical line to get to the ISP gear to reach the internet backbone.

A good example is ISP with multiple technology, like DOCSYS3 and lower. Usually they are configured to have different type of switch to support both technology on the physical layer to reach the backbone, but the path stay almost the same, just the technology is not the same.

Your result simply depend of where and what you tested it over. Someone with a static, but on a slow modem cable versus a dynamic on a fiber ISP in example could make your test result not ok.

Comment: That's not the point, and that doesn't answer my main question. Still why my traceroute shows completely a different route only to their static ip but not the dynamic ones? That not normal at all.

Comment: Any router in between can *not* accept to reply the ICMP request for the trace route output to work. For the static versus dynamic IP, it's the same network, see my answer.

Comment: Wrong, that's not the case. But It's ok, I'll be waiting for more answers.

Comment: You tell me that the cable between your house and the ISP concentrator is not routed the same as someone near you going in the same concentrator ?

Comment: Ops sorry, but i've changed my mind. I don't like your answer anymore.

Comment: @Semphie94 I work for an ISP, then read a book and learn before trolling

Comment: Ok. That a little bit messed up. But thanks anyway. i'll try to read your answer one more time to be sure. i'll accept it though! :)